# Correct window.onload call on a Javascript-generated page

Tags: javascript

There is a JS function on a simple HTML page (let it be `function a()`) creating a new HTML page via `window.open("")` and then calling scripts on that page after it's loaded. Let `function b()` be `window.onload()` on this new page and `newWindow` be its window.

I have an issue with correct invoking of `b`.

What I have currently done is set `window.onload = b` in generated code and `setTimeout(newWindow.b, 0)` in function `a`. That worked well until I replaced `<script>code...</script>` with `<script src='...'></script>` on the new page. Here's a brief example of how it looks:

```
function a() {
    var newWindow = window.open("");
    var d = newWindow.document;
    var script1 = d.createElement("script");
    var script2 = d.createElement("script");
    script1.type = "text/javascript";
    script2.type = "text/javascript";
    script1.src = firstScriptSource;  // external source
    script2.innerHTML = "\n\
        function b() {\n\
            //...here goes the code depending on script1 and DOM
        }\n\
        window.onload = b;";
    //...here goes some new page constructing
    d.head.appendChild(script1);
    d.head.appendChild(script2);
    setTimeout(newWindow.b, 0);
}

myButton.addEventListener("click", a);
```

After replacing internal scripts with external, it seems that some time is needed to load them and `setTimeout(newWindow.b, 0);` would just call `newWindow.undefined` after a small delay. I can, however, change timeout to 1000 or more/less and that'll do, but that's more like gambling.

What is a solution to always call `b` in time?

Answer (score 0):

From `script2`, you can select `script1`'s tag and listen to its `load` event, and then execute `b`:

```
function a() {
  var newWindow = window.open("");
  var d = newWindow.document;
  var script1 = d.createElement('script');
  script1.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
  d.head.appendChild(script1);
  var script2 = d.createElement("script");
  script2.textContent = `
    function b() {
      console.log('b');
      console.log(typeof $);
    }
    var script1 = document.head.querySelector('script');
    script1.addEventListener('load', b);
  `;
  d.head.appendChild(script2);
}

document.addEventListener("click", a);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0u78v6gj/2/

(cannot insert live snippet because stack snippet sandboxing prevents window opening)

The newly created empty document will have *already* `load`ed (and `DOMContentLoaded`) before the script is inserted.